# Form inside form laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two form one inside other the firstone is with the methode post but the seconde one with the methode delete.

so i tried to make just one form and inside the form  (button and Input) submit .. using the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitForm(action) {
    var form = document.getElementById('work');
    form.action = action;
    form.submit();
  }
```

But the problem is that the method delete use this : 
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

helper to generate the _method input ,so its should be inside the form of deleting .. but now i have just one form so this instruction execute for the two submit ..

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: You cannot have nested forms. It's against the HTML specification and will not be (reliably) supported by browsers.

Comment: ukay thank so do u have any idea about my issue ?

Comment: Separate the forms. And why are you using JavaScript to just submit a form? If it does nothing else, just use the native functionality.

Comment: but the problem is that i have a form delete inside form post .. cus i want to delete the images of a product inside the edit of product

Comment: I know that's what your problem is. And I'm saying it's not possible to have nested forms. So either separate the forms, change the image deletion to use AJAX or try something else.

Comment: ukaaay I understand now thank you so much for your help Sir , i appreciate your help